# WP Rest API convert permalink to post ID for fetch

Tags: rest-api

I'm in the process of converting my existing WordPress site to use Preact/Redux on the frontend and use the WP REST API to get post data back from the admin.

I'll be using React Router and a rewrite in .htaccess to rewrite the URLs to the index.html file, and React Router should handle the requests.

Given an existing URL of `https://peteschuster.com/2017/10/high-praise-react-react-ecosystem/` I assume I'll setup my route as `/:year/:month/:slug`

My question is, how would I use those params to get the post ID so I can call the REST endpoint for: `GET /wp/v2/posts/<id>`?

Perhaps there is another way to achieve this? I tried several combinations of:
`https://peteschuster.com/wp/v2/posts/2017/10/high-praise-react-react-ecosystem/` to no avail. I was thinking it might be possible similar to how `/feed` is handled like:
`https://peteschuster.com/2017/10/high-praise-react-react-ecosystem/json`

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core rewrite API does offer the function `url_to_postid()` (as mentioned by @stephen-sabatini) which can find a post ID from a URL. However it seems less than ideal to have to make a request up front just to determine the post ID...

The REST API does not natively offer the ability to query by date beyond setting `before` and `after` args so that won't be of much help to you.

You could potentially ignore the date params and query by slug. For example:

```
https://peteschuster.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=high-praise-react-react-ecosystem
```

Alternatively, you could make a custom endpoint and perform whatever type of query you want. Check the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) for more information.

On the idea of a `/json` endpoint: This isn't something that exists natively, but it is certainly doable.

To implement it, have a look at rewrite endpoints:

- [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)
- [Code reference page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/)
- [Blog post with more info on using rewrite endpoints](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/)

Keep in mind that this would be completely separate from the REST API, however you could probably reuse the REST API internally with something like:

```
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/posts' );
$request->set_param( 'slug', 'high-praise-react-react-ecosystem' );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
$post = $response->data;
```

Using the REST API in this way is briefly touched on in the [handbook FAQ](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-make%c2%a0api-requests%c2%a0from-php-within-a-plugin).

This would add some extra complexity to your server config, as now you would have to route requests ending in `json` straight to WordPress instead of your frontend, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

Hopefully that gives you some ideas...

Comment: thanks, the slug filtering is what I'm going to use. I didn't want to go to the server to retrieve the posts ID only to make another request for the posts data. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would add my two cents to this.

using `wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=` works very well until you start working with **parent & child** pages.

No two pages can have the same slug UNLESS one of the pages is the child off another page.
Here's a quick example where I have a page called lorem-2 (the -2 was added automatically cause I already had a paged called lorem).

Then I added a child page called lorem-2 to lorem, then when I query for lorem-2 I get two pages.

A safer rout would be to make a custom REST route that let's you query the **whole** URL as that will provide you with the exact post/page

[image]

Comment: That's a good point, passing the parent ID will prevent this issue. `wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=x&parent=y`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the REST API URL base would be:

https://peteschuster.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

I'm not sure I understand your question as a whole, but if you're trying to get the ID from the post URL, you can use `url_to_postid($url);`.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid

The full URL would be:
`https://peteschuster.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ID_HERE`

e.g.
https://peteschuster.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/4177

You can also get the post by the slug using a query: (I'd probably recommend)

https://peteschuster.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=high-praise-react-react-ecosystem

You can get the slug either by using `$post->post_name` or `basename(get_permalink());`.

Comment: The `filter` param was dropped in v2 of the API - you can still query by slug though: https://peteschuster.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=high-praise-react-react-ecosystem

Comment: thanks for your help, `?slug=:slug` is what I'm going to go with.